# How to get the selected value from a list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hyperlink, click

I am new to `angularjs` and `javascript`.I am using a `contextmenu` in the `text-angular`. So, My code is like -

```
<div contextmenu="meta.contextmenu" class="dropdown contextmenu ">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-content" role="menu" ng-if="showdropdownForProject" id="projectAnnotation">
                <li>
                    <a role="menu" href
                    ng-click="sendInfo()">
                    <span>ABC</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a role="menu" href
                    ng-click="sendInfo()">
                    <span>PQR</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a role="menu" href
                    ng-click="sendInfo()">
                    <span>XYZ</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
</div>
```

So, Here I am not able to get the selected value in the controller . So, How can I get that value , If I click on the `ABC`, I need this value so that I can send it to backend. Thanks in advance.

Comment: either you can pass value in function sendnfo('bla') or try using/adding ng-model in context menu

Comment: @ganeshk, it is working for you ?

Comment: Yes it is working. I am using the second solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass value to `sendInfo()` method.

```
<li>              
   <a role="menu" href="" ng-click="sendInfo('ABC')">
        <span>ABC</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

JS

```
$scope.sendInfo=function(info){
     console.log(info);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create array items for it to use `ng-repeat`.

Controller:

```
$scope.items = [
  {
    name: 'ABC'
  },
  {
    name: 'BCD'
  },
  {
    name: 'XYZ'
  }
];

$scope.selectedItem = {};

$scope.sendInfo(item) {
  $scope.selectedItem = item;
  console.log($scope.selectedItem.name);
}
```

Template:

```
<div contextmenu="meta.contextmenu" class="dropdown contextmenu ">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-content" role="menu" ng-if="showdropdownForProject" id="projectAnnotation">
      <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
          <a role="menu" href
          ng-click="sendInfo(item)">
          <span>{{item.name}}</span>
          </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```